# Help in recovering BTC from seed phrase

Tags: multibit, seed

So 6-7 years ago I had some bitcoin, and as with many I forgot about it...

I since found my notes which contain a 12 word seed phrase. I think (I may be wrong) I used Multibit so I reinstalled and fired this up and tried to restore the wallet from seed.

Multibit asks for the seed, then syncs, then asks for a date - which I don't have. If I leave this blank and continue  it just reverts back to the start dialogue where you can create a wallet, restore etc.

I also tried importing the seed into Electrum using this guide: https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-multibithd-wallet-in-electrum/
I.e. setting the derivation path etc. But the wallet just comes up blank listing no transactions.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: "reverts back" this seems to be a bug, restoring without the datestamp is supported. Unfortunately I can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

Like MCCCS said, the fact that it goes back to the start screen is a bug. Try installing an older version of MultiBit, and use that.

EDIT: Don't use Multibit. From the readme:

> Dear Bitcoin Community,

> It is time for us to let Multibit go.

> KeepKey acquired Multibit a little over 1 year ago. At the time, the engineers who originally built and supported Multibit had announced that they would no longer be working on it or providing support. Multibit played an important role in the Bitcoin infrastructure. We felt that it was important for Multibit to continue and hoped that with our existing support and development teams, we would be able to keep Multibit alive.

> The reality is that Multibit is in need of a lot of work. It has stubborn bugs that have caused us and Multibit users much grief. Additionally, Bitcoin has gone through a fundamental change in regards to the way fees work. The addition of SegWit in the coming weeks will mean the Multibit software has fallen still further behind.

> Unfortunately, KeepKey simply does not have the resources to support the current issues, nor to rebuild Multibit to ensure ideal user experience. By focusing our attention on the KeepKey device, we will continue building and improving the best hardware wallet available.

> Thus, KeepKey will discontinue support and maintenance of Multibit, effective immediately.

> We recommend that all Multibit users discontinue using it and you move your keys to other wallet software of your choosing.

I would try using the electrum wallet, but **DO NOT** select to use SegWit addresses. Use the legacy addresses when restoring the wallet.

Comment: Them you but I've tried electrum as per the guide linked above, and I've chosen legacy over segwit. I just get a blank wallet with no transactions.

Comment: yeah, I was wrong you need to use an old version of multibit and transfer the funds to an electrum wallet because electrum and multibit are incompatible

Comment: for the date, just input jan 3 2009

Comment: This should be obvious, but I would recommend that you **do not send your seed to strangers on the internet**. Keep your conversation in public so others can help you avoid bad advice, and never share any sensitive information.

Comment: @5ynt4x_3rr0r_: Thank you for helping Nick, but please refrain from trying to get people to send you key material privately.